# check box not working

Tags: android

I need your assistance in my following scenario.

I have three checkboxes A, B and C and variables a. If I click on Checkbox B, the value of a should be kept 2 and if I check A then this should be changed to 3 and if I deselect it should go back to 2.

How to obtain this dynamically?

I am using onCheckedChangeListener which changes the variable only when I change the checked state of the checkboxes.

Any help is much appreciated.

few codes:

Code for ChkBxA :

```
    ChkBxA.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) 
    {
        if (buttonView.isChecked()) 
        {
            variable_a = 1;
        }
        else 
        {
            variable_a = 0;
        }
    }
});
```

ChkBxB Code:

```
ChkBxB.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) 
    {
        if (buttonView.isChecked()) 
        {
            if(variable_a == 1)
            {
                variable_b = 3;
            }
            else 
            {
                variable_b = 2;

            }
        }
        else 
        {
            variable_b = 0;
        }
    }
});
```

The issue is as the value of variable_a changes when the state of the checkbox A, the value of variable_b doesn't change as this is within the checkedChangeListener. So any advice to overcome this is much appreciated.

Comment: Explain what kind of variables are `variable_a` and `variable_b`. If they belong to the same class, you can set then both together?

Comment: they are just two different variables just to keep a track of the state of the corresponding checkboxes. but the variables b is dependant on the values of variable a, which means indirectly on the checkbox A's state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one single method which calculates the values depending on the checked state:

```
void CalculateValues(bool CheckBoxA, bool CheckBoxB)
{
  variable_a = CheckBoxA ? 1 : 0;
  variable_b = CheckBoxB? (variable_a==1 ? 3 : 2) : 0;
}
```

now simply call this method from both event handlers and pass the checked state of both checkboxes. in fact, the event handler (the call) will be identical for both checkboxes. I don't know how you can retrieve the checked state from your ChkBxA, but let's assume it's easy:

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) 
{
  CalculateValues(ChkBxA.IsChecked(), ChkBxB.IsChecked() );
}
```

Comment: Let me try this method and get back to you soon if it is working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Write below condition...

```
if (isChecked()) //<<===buttonView remove
{
    if(variable_a == 1)
    {
           variable_b = 3;
     }
     else 
     {
           variable_b = 2;

     }
}
```

Comment: my problem is not the condition not working. if I select one checkbox or deselect the same I need the value of the variable to be recalculated. just like when u click a chkbx in a webpage it refresh and the changes occur using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Though your question is not clear, but after getting your comment in previous answers, probably I found a way to solve this.

You may use a `stack` to store the current checkbox value. Value of **TOS** will be your checkbox selection value. By using `onCheckedChangeListener()` and using the proper logic you may change the value of TOS [using `push()` or `pop()`].. I think you may get the current selection or previous selection using this way.

This is just an Idea, you have to implement the logic :) Good Luck !!